# How do I change a variable with the change of a select option in an html form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, parameters

I am trying to change my variable, "year", whenever the user changes his answer in a selection list in my html form. I want to change "year" to whatever year is currently selected, so if the user selects "2022," I want my variable year to be equal to 2022. I tried using "event" as my parameter for my function setYear(), but that was unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var year;

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setYear(a) {
        year = a;
    }
</script>

<form>
    <tr>
        <td>Year: </td>
        <td><select name="Year" onchange="setYear(event)">
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
            <option value="2022">2022</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: `year = a.target.value` did you mean this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
var year;

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setYear(a) {
        year = a;
    }
</script>

<form>
    <tr>
        <td>Year: </td>
        <td><select name="Year" onchange="setYear(event)">
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
            <option value="2022">2022</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

You are declaring variable `var` outside `<script>` tag. Because, `var` is declared outside of `<script>` tag, it will not visible to the javaScript function. 
 Also, you are seting `var` to the event argument. 
This code might work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var year;
    function setYear(a) {
        year = a;
    }
</script>

<form>
    <tr>
        <td>Year: </td>
        <td><select name="Year" onchange="setYear(this.value)">
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
            <option value="2022">2022</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Dont declare `var` outside script.

  ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var year;
      function setYear(a) {
          year = a.target.value;
      }
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

first, define `var year` define inside the `script` and then get `a.target.value` and use it whenever you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var year;
    function setYear(a) {
        year = a.target.value;
        console.log(year);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to reference the select DOM element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let year
  function setYear(a) {
    year = a
  }
</script>

<select name="Year" onchange="setYear(this.value)">
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>
```

Inline JavaScript like this is a bit outdated however. For a more modern approach, use `document.querySelector` to get the DOM node, and register an event listener that fires when it changes. This way, you don't have to mix HTML and JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let year
  const yearSelect = document.querySelector('#yearSelect')

  yearSelect.addEventListener('change', e => {
    year = e.target.value
  })
</script>

<select id="yearSelect" name="Year">
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not be using `<td>` and `<tr>` without a `<table>` tag.
The `<tr>` tag defines the table rows.
The `<td>` tag defines the standard cells in the table.

Then, in the onchange event you should pass `this` as a parameter. It will reference the select DOM element of your HTML. In your function you will now be able to know which year of your select was selected.

`select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;`
**select:** Your DOM element.
**options:** All the options of your select as an array
**select.selectedIndex:** The index selected by the user (Corresponds to a number)
**value:** The value of the selected option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label>Year:</label>
      <select name="Year" onchange="setYear(this)">
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
      </select>
     </form>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var year;
    function setYear(select) {
        year = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```